# PHP Alterar palavra de uma vindo de uma variavel

Tags: php

Pessoal como posso fazer com php a seguinte situacao:

tenho uma variável que esta vindo a seguinte informação exemplo:

$nome_do_arquivo = "/wp-content/uploads/1.avi";

como faco para alterar apenas essa extencao final em vez de 1.avi gostria que fosse 1.mp4

achei esse codigo mais nao esta funcionando segue abaixo

```html
$str = $nome_do_arquivo;
str_ireplace(".avi",".mp4",$str);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$nome_do_arquivo = "/wp-content/uploads/1.avi";
$str = str_ireplace(".avi", ".mp4", $nome_do_arquivo);
```

Strings são imutáveis em PHP. Elas ocupam um espaço determinado na pilha de memória, e quando você tenta modifica-las, é possível que seu novo tamanho seja diferente, e por isso é necessário alocar essa nova string em outro espaço da memória que possa armazena-la.

Como resultado, sempre que você modifica uma string, uma nova é criada, e você precisa armazenar essa nova string numa nova variável, ou reatribuir o valor na variável antiga.